# How do you get to 1000 before 666 of Earth investments?

Tags: steam, achievements, adventure-capitalist

In looking at the list of achievements for [adventure-capitalist](/questions/tagged/adventure-capitalist) I see that more people have gotten *Grand Standing!* than have *Ominous...* yet everybody that has *Grand Standing!* should already have *Ominous...* since *Grand Standing!* requires 1000 things while *Ominous...* requires 666 of seemingly the same set of things.  How is this possible?

[image: achievements]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ominous achievement was introduced in an update, which explain why less people got it.

On the 16th of June 2015, [patch 1.1.1](http://steamcommunity.com/games/346900/announcements/detail/198503889249922237) added Earth achievements and on 23rd of July 2015, [patch 1.1.2](http://steamcommunity.com/games/346900/announcements/detail/106183718176122957) added achievements too.

I can't find which of them added Ominous but this [guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=424373495) was last updated on the 26th of July which include the Ominous achievement with the update, so my guess is that the 1.1.2 patch added it.

So while it's now technically impossible to get the Grand Standing! achievement before Ominous, it is possible to have gotten it before Ominous was in the game and never went back to get the Ominous achievement.

Comment: I was afraid it was *another* bug, but this makes a lot more sense.  Thanks Jonathan.

Answer (score -1):

It technically isn't possible as you said, but that may be an issue in Steam or the way it reports the progress from the program.  Unfortunately i'm not a steam developer, so i can't answer how that part works.

@Jonathan I've gotten both achievements, and it is based on the number of companies you have on earth.  Each company is just called an investment, and there are 10 total.  The only difference is there's 10 for the earth, 10 for the moon, and now 9 for mars.

Comment: True but your answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's not really possible to answer that question.  The best you can do is find something that's as close to what the OP is looking for.  That's more of a program error, and what you found may explain it better and it still doesn't answer the question of why.